# Placing UI elements "on top of each other" using FlexLayout in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

### My goals:

1. Place an `Editor` inside of a `Frame`, and the editor never expand outside of the frame, no matter how much text is supplied.
2. Place an `ActivityIndicator` 'inside' a `Button` (and make the `Button` text not visible when `IsBusy`).
3. Make it relative for different sized devices.

### My questions

1. Is there a way to make these controls appear 'on top' of each other using `FlexLayout`?
2. Could there be another, more appropriate, layout for my problem?

---

### Current setup:

[image]

---

### What I'd like it to look like:

[image]

---

### The current XAML

```
<!--  This is where the main content on the slide up menu starts  -->
        <Frame
            Grid.Row="1"
            BorderColor="white"
            CornerRadius="0"
            HasShadow="True"
            OutlineColor="White">

            <FlexLayout
                AlignItems="Center"
                Direction="Column"
                JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly">

                <!--  Title  -->
                <Label
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Medium"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{util:Translate Viewtitle}" />

                <!--  Scrollable text  -->
                <ScrollView
                    x:Name="ActionViewScroller"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Margin="10"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
                    <Label Text="{Binding ActionText}" />
                </ScrollView>

                <!--  Text box for optional notes  -->
                <Frame
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="10"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    BorderColor="LightGray"
                    CornerRadius="0"
                    FlexLayout.Gorw="1"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    WidthRequest="280" />
                <Editor
                    x:Name="ActionViewNotes"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="15"
                    AutoSize="TextChanges"
                    FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"
                    Keyboard="Default"
                    MaxLength="150"
                    Placeholder="{util:Translate PlaceholderText}"
                    Text="{Binding ConsentNotes, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="280" />


                <!--  Submit Button  -->
                <Button
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    AlignSelf="Stretch"                      
                    Command="{Binding DoSomething}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Source={Reference TheNotes}, Path=Text}"
                    HeightRequest="70"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource NegateBooleanConverter}}"
                    Style="{StaticResource TertiaryButtonStyle}"
                    Text="{util:Translate DoSomethingText}"
                    WidthRequest="350" />
                <ActivityIndicator
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Margin="5"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                    Style="{DynamicResource BaseActivityIndicatorStyle}" />

            </FlexLayout>
        </Frame>
```

---

Comment: There will be some custom renderers that you might need for eg for the button thing the rest i think you can do it without an issue without even using a flexlayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Is there a way to make these controls appear 'on top' of each other using FlexLayout?

Yes, you can put the `editor` on top of `Frame` in your case. It is the same as you put a `Frame` inside a `Flexlayout`. I added some `backgroundColor` to the controls to make it clear.

Here is a example of put the `editor` inside `Frame`:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Frame
            Grid.Row="1"
            BorderColor="white"
            CornerRadius="0"
            HasShadow="True"
            OutlineColor="White">

            <FlexLayout
                AlignItems="Center"
                Direction="Column"
                JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly">

                <!--  Title  -->
                <Label
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Medium"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    BackgroundColor="Green"
                    Text=" Viewtitle" />

                <!--  Scrollable text  -->
                <ScrollView
                    x:Name="ActionViewScroller"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Margin="10"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
                    <Label Text="123" />
                </ScrollView>

                <!--  Text box for optional notes  -->
                <Frame
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="10"
                    BorderColor="LightGray"
                    CornerRadius="0"
                    FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    WidthRequest="280"
                    BackgroundColor="Red">

                    <!--  Put your Editor inside Frame here  -->          
                    <Editor
                    x:Name="ActionViewNotes"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="15"
                    AutoSize="TextChanges"
                    FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"
                    Keyboard="Default"
                    MaxLength="150"
                    Placeholder="PlaceholderText"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="280"
                    BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"/>

                </Frame>
            </FlexLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
```

> 2.Could there be another, more appropriate, layout for my problem?

There are several ways to achieve the layout for your problem. You can use `StackLayout`,`AbsoluteLayout`,`RelativeLayout`,`Grid` and so on. In my opinion, which to choose depending on yourself. Each way has its own advantages. `Flexlayout` is more conveniently to arrange its children horizontally and vertically in a stack.

You can refer to the official documents about `layout`.There are several demos similar with your layout and you can get the advantages of each layout option from there.

[Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I can't believe how simple that solution was. Suppose that's what happens when you get tunnel vision!